# Throttling ajax requests in firefox

Tags: firefox, tabbed-browsing

Is there a tool or extension available to allow me to throttle the number of Ajax requests a tab in firefox might invoke?  When having 50+ tabs open, xmlhttprequests start consuming more CPU and network bandwidth (especially when I'm tethered to a 3G data connection) that I don't want to spend.

But I use firefox as a work-in-progress slate - I'm not open to reducing my tab usage.

Answer (score 1):

To me you have two options:

1. Try [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/), [Tab Utilities](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59961/), or any other addon than can "lock" a tab and see if it works for you. I'm not sure about background requests, but its worth a try.
2. All requests that aren't initiated by you are initiated by timers. If you have greasemonkey, here's some code that can kill all of the timers on the page:

   ```
   GM_registerMenuCommand('TimerKill - Kill all timers',function() { main(); });

   function main() {
      for(var i=0; i<500; i++) { window.clearTimeout(i); }
   }
   ```

Once again its worth a try.